# Primes arising from permutations (II)

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers, permutations

In Question 315259 (cf. [Primes arising from permutations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315259)) I asked a question on primes arising from permutations which looks quite challenging.

Here I pose a new question in this direction which does not involve upper bounds for the least prime in an arithmetic progression with common difference $n$.

QUESTION: Is my following conjecture true?

**Conjecture**. (i) For each $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, there is a permutation $\pi_n$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $k^2+k\pi_n(k)+\pi_n(k)^2$ is prime for every $k=1,\ldots,n$.

(ii) For any positive integer $n\not=7$, there is a permutation $\pi_n$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $k^2+\pi_n(k)^2$ is prime for every $k=1,\ldots,n$.

(iii) For each $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, the number of permutations $\pi_n$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $k^2+\pi_n(k)^2$ prime for all $k=1,\ldots,n$, is always a square.

I have checked this conjecture for $n$ up to $11$. For example, $(6,3,2,5,4,1)$ is the unique permutation of $\{1,\ldots,6\}$ meeting the requirement in part (i) with $n=6$, and $(1,3,2,5,4)$ is the unique permutation of $\{1,\ldots,5\}$ meeting the requirement in part (ii) with $n=5$. Part (iii) of the conjecture looks quite mysterious!

Let $r(n)$ be the number of permutations $\pi_n$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ meeting the requirement in part (i), and let $s(n)$ be the number of permutations $\pi_n$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ meeting the requirement in part (ii). Then 
$$(r(1),\ldots,r(11))=(1,1,3,1,5,1,17,9,21,16,196)$$
and 
$$(s(1),\ldots,s(11))=(1,1,1,1,1,4,0,16,4,144,64).$$

Comment: $r(2n)$ might be a square too.

Comment: The argument from my answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315351 confirms (iii) as well, so nothing _that_ mysterious happens...

Comment: ...and the same happens for $r(2n)$, since all even numbers should map to all odd ones. This is what breaks in the odd case here: there may be diffetent pairs of odd numbers providng a prime.

Comment: Affirmative answer to (i) or (ii) would imply that for every $k$, a degree $2$ polynomial $x^2+k^2$ or $x^2+xk+k^2$ takes a prime value. I am willing to bet this is an open problem.

Comment: You confirmed conjectures (ii) and (iii) through n=11. Here are the number of partitions for conjecture (iii) for n=12 through 25": 81, 256, 5184, 1600, 25600, 8100, 183184, 108900, 5924356, 342225, 9066121, 11356900, 106853569, 105698961 - they are all squares.

Comment: Thank you for your computation and the values of $s(12),\ldots,s(26)$.

Comment: I've calculated n=12 through 25 for the related problem with 4th powers instead of squares and added them to sequence A321611. Note that for this version, there are no such permutations for n=12, a counterexample to the conjecture for 4th powers.

Comment: I got three more terms of the sequence (all squares), so the sequence is 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 0, 16, 4, 144, 64, 81, 256, 5184, 1600, 25600, 8100, 183184, 108900, 5924356, 342225, 9066121, 11356900, 106853569, 105698961, 16119349444, 1419933124, 69792129124.

Comment: And note that the related sequence A321611 has a 0 as the 12th term: 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 64, 16, 144, 144, 0, 144, 144, 289, 4356, 2916, 22500, 79524, 1887876, 313600, 3459600, 2985984, 50069776, 32353344, 2056803904, 237591396.